# Multiple Distinct Microsoft Graph API Calls in Office Add-ins

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I am working on a project which was generated with the Yeoman - Office Add-ins generator. The project is configured as a Word Web Add-In with has SSO (Single Sign-On) and is written in TypeScript. In this project I am trying to make several distinct Microsoft Graph API calls.

In the .ENV file within this project the GRAPH_URL_SEGMENT is specified. This is the API URL we call.

How does one specify the URL elsewhere in the code, so it is possible to make other calls beside the one that is specified in the .ENV file?

Comment: Yes, the ./.ENV file in the root directory of the project defines constants that are used by the add-in project. You can look at the [documentation/sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart) it talks about the same calling various Graph API call varies from initialize the addin, using the Office JavaScript API library to add the data from Microsoft Graph to the Office document, authentication etc. Also you can [get it started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph) from here as well.

Comment: I have been reading the documentation before I asked the question, nowhere does it specify how to setup multiple API calls. However in the meanwhile I have found out how to get it setup, I am just surprised that it was not mentioned in the official documentation.

Comment: Please go ahead, share your findings here - it can be useful to others as well :)

Comment: Yes please, share your solution. It would be very useful to me.